# MVC in qt and problem with interfaces

Tags: model-view-controller, qt, interface

I want to create view and pass it into to controller via constructor.

So, I've created interface:

```
#include <QString>

class IMainView
{
public:
    virtual ~IMainView() {}
    virtual void setWindowTitle1(QString &title) = 0;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(IMainView, "IMainView/1.0");
```

Then I created view:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, IMainView
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(IMainView)
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void setWindowTitle1(QString &title);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

MainWindow from IMainView.
Now I have to pass instance of IMainView to controller, because each controller register view:

```
#include "maincontroller.h"


MainController::MainController(IMainView *v)
{
    QString title = "my application";
    v->setWindowTitle1(title);
}

MainController::MainController()
{
}
```

And I got error:
e:\pm\pm\mainapplication\IMainView.h:13: error: C2259: 'IMainView' : cannot instantiate abstract class
due to following members:
'void IMainView::setWindowTitle1(QString &)' : is abstract

In C# it works, but in QT not.

Thanks

---

Sorry, wrong question. The problem is with interface, which is abstract class (iMainView.h):

```
#include <QString>

class IMainView
{
public:
    virtual ~IMainView() {}
    virtual void setWindowTitle1(QString &title) = 0;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(IMainView, "IMainView/1.0");
```

and this class have to be attached to mainwindow header file (mainwindow.h):

```
#ifndef MAINCONTROLLER_H
#define MAINCONTROLLER_H

#include "IMainView.h"  //here is error


class MainController
{
public:
    //MainController(IMainView *v);
    MainController();


};

#endif // MAINCONTROLLER_H
```

and I got error:

e:\pm\pm\mainapplication\IMainView.h:13: error: C2259: 'IMainView' : cannot instantiate abstract class
due to following members:
'void IMainView::setWindowTitle1(QString &)' : is abstract

Thanks

Comment: Which line is line 13 that it's complaining about.

Comment: Somewhere, you are declaring or trying to instantiate a plain IMainView instance, which isn't allowed.  If it isn't in your code, you could try double-checking the preprocessed code generated by the Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement setWindowTitle1 in class MainWindow, which you probably missed. That's plain C++ and not special to Qt.

Comment: Ok, I know that is not Qt but c++. Function setWindowTitle1 is implemented in mainwindow.cpp. 
Error occurs when I call #include "IMainView.h"  in maincontroller header class.

Comment: Why accept this answer then? Problem seems to be unsolved... I have the same problem and everything is implemented as it should :/

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to

```
> #include <QObject>
```

Somewhere above your interface declaration.  QObject.h contains the definition of Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE and its dependencies.